# How to launch programmatically a video even in chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I ask some help because I want to create a little video in my webpage, which launch herself when the user move the mouse over it.  I created a  balise, and a javascript event. In Edge, it's works perfectly. But in chrome, the video is played only when I mute the sound. I understand why : Chrome consider that a sound shouldn't be play without a real action of the user. Great, but for me, move the mouse over the picture is an action to play the video. (Like in Netflix website, when you have a little preview when you move over the picture)

I think this action could it be possible, because it's exactly the same in websites like Netflix. Is anyone has an idea how make it works ? Thank you.

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: Its not clear do you want sound? Or just to be able to play it? Generally, though you don't play the video as-is, you create a set of screens, then iterate through them or if you want a video, you would need to encode a small part of the video optimised for the display size, with no sound, in perhaps webm etc.

Comment: Yes, I want the sound and that's the problem. In fact, I created a set of little screens with fixed pictures. When the user let the mouse on one picture, the video start. If before I muted the sound of the video, chrome let the video start. But if I don't mute the sound - and that what I want - chrome don't want to play the video.  In websites like Netflix, there is sound in this little preview videos.